# TYPO3 Redirect to ShowAction af creating post

Tags: typo3

I am building my own extension using extension_builder.
I need it to go to the Show Action after putting the data into the database.

This is my create action

```php
/**
 * action create
 * 
 * @param \Originalen\OrigWhistleblower\Domain\Model\Whistleblower $newWhistleblower
 * @return void
 */
public function createAction(\Originalen\OrigWhistleblower\Domain\Model\Whistleblower $newWhistleblower)
{
    $this->whistleblowerRepository->add($newWhistleblower);

    $this->redirect('show', 'Whistleblower', 'orig_whistleblower', ['whistleblower' => $this]);
    //$this->redirect('show');
}
```

But I get an error saying that `Required argument "whistleblower" is not set for Originalen\OrigWhistleblower\Controller\WhistleblowerController->show.`

Comment: Oehm, `$this` in the third argument is your controller, not a whistleblower object...

Comment: But what should it be instead? I think I have tried everything, and googled a lot. Noting works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your object to the arguments. Your `$this` variable is the actual class not the new object. You should replace it with the `$newWhistleblower`.

```
$this->redirect('show', 'Whistleblower', 'orig_whistleblower', ['whistleblower' => $newWhistleblower]);
```

At the same time i would persist it before the direct, just to make sure (save it in the database. The `add->()` command doesnt save the object yet).

```
$this->persistenceManager->persistAll();
```

Comment: Maybe I should just start over again with Extension Builder. Now I get this error: Could not serialize Domain Object Originalen\OrigWhistleblower\Domain\Model\Whistleblower. It is neither an Entity with identity properties set, nor a Value Object.